# I am getting this error while training my model PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/p300'

Tags: permissionerror

I searched for it but it tells this comes if any other folder has the same file opened but checked it no other folder has this file opened.

I feel it is not able to search the path of os.py in conda env as it cant read many folders.

Comment: Give some more context. Where is your program located at? What OS, architecture, and spinoff are you using? How are you training your model? How does your directory tree look like?